# How many functions there is from 3 element set to 2 element set?

Tags: combinatorics

Let say we have a set A = {a,b,c} and B={1,2}. How many functions are there from A to B?

This seems like elementary question, but my class mate argued that there is no difference between: $f_1(t)=1$ and $f_2(t)=2$, that's just crazy.

I think there are 8 different functions, is that right?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: If there were no distiction between $f_1(t) = 1$ and $f_2(t) = 2$, the problem would have asked about the number of "essentially different functions", "functions up to permutation of $A$ and $B$", or something along those lines. In this case there are two, one constant and one non-constant.

Answer (score 4):

You're right. More generally, if $A$ is a set of size $m$ and $B$ is a set of size $n$ then there are $n^m$ functions $A \to B$.

Why? Because for each of the $m$ elements of $A$ there are $n$ choices of elements of $B$, so you have
$$\underbrace{n \times n \times \cdots \times n}_{m\ \text{times}} = n^m$$
choices in total.

In fact, this is often taken as a definition of exponentiation of natural numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As Igor Rifkin says in a comment, you are correct.